# Echo text inside JS in WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have following code:

```
  var led = <?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>;
  var optics = <?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>;
  var ledil = <?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>;

  function toLED() {
    document.getElementById("change-box").innerHTML = "<p class='small'>" + led + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.color = "white";
}
```

There are also two more methods for the second and third text box.
The problem is, I don't seem to find a way to actually echo the text.
I'm just going between function not defined and syntax errors for PHP.

I want to get text from the ACF field "why_led" and then echo it to JS box and save it to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option one: Put vars inside func

```
  function toLED() {
    var led = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
    var optics = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
    var ledil = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";

    document.getElementById("change-box").innerHTML = "<p class='small'>" + led + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.color = "white";
}
```

Option two: assign them to window

```
  window.led = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
  window.optics = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
  window.ledil = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";

  function toLED() {

    document.getElementById("change-box").innerHTML = "<p class='small'>" + window.led + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.color = "white";
   }
```

Comment: both of these for some reason echo  window.led = <p>Why LED box</p> i have no idea where this tag + text is coming (vars inside func obviously without window. but still same error)

Comment: @Clomez see edit you hadn't put `""` around the php echo thing

Comment: Okey, the problem was that i was using wyswig editor... it adds p tags by itself... which kinda messes with the code.

Answer (score 2):

You have not applied quotes " " while assigning a php value to JS variable.
Apply Quotes and write the variables inside the function and it will work.

```
function toLED() {
     var led = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
     var optics = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
     var ledil = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";

    document.getElementById("change-box").innerHTML = "<p class='small'>" + led + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("p-button").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button2").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("p-button3").style.color = "white";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question,

It depend on your input data "why_led" here.

If it is a string, your current code won't work.

You should change it to:

```
var led = "<?php echo get_field('why_led'); ?>";
alert(led);
```

By the way, you can use console in grome or firefox to see the errors